# How to zoom out a document printed with the standard .NET PrintDocument class?

Tags: .net, printing, scale, printdocument

We have some routines which exploit the standard .NET `PrintDocument` class to print our documents. However, some documents we would like to see on 1 printable page do not fit the standard paper sheet. Is there an easy way to zoom them out using the properties of `PrintDocument` - such as PageSettings, PrinterSettings?

Comment: You can arbitrarily scale output by using e.Graphics.ScaleTransform() in your PrintPage event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant, `e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(0.5F, 0.5F)` really works in the PrintPage event. However, this approach cannot be used in our case. The printing routines I'm talking about are in another DLL we can't modify, and they draw the documents before our PrintPage event is fired (there is a PrintPage event handler in the DLL which is executed before our one). Is there another way to specify the scale factor for the whole print work?

Comment: @HansPassant, place also your comment as answer so I can mark it as accepted answer :)